# Can parent Activity be terminated before onActivityResult is called

Tags: android

Is it possible for the parent activity to be terminated before onActivityResult() is called? If that's the case, then whatever local variables are maintained in the parent activity, may not be valid (initialized) when onActivityResult() is called.

I periodically get null pointer exception when onActivityResult() is called for some variables that were originally set in the parent activity, but if the parent activity had been destroyed before return from the child activity, then these variables will no long be valid.

Comment: Paste your code. In onActivityResult and logcat. You are trying to run function on null object.

Comment: So, this is the case: Activity A calls for result to an Activity B. Activity B does its stuff and then it finishes and then Activity A is on the screen again. Activity A should execute its onActivityResult method. But isn't open because it was already finished. This has non sense. There's nothing to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible for the parent activity to be terminated before onActivityResult() is called?

Activities are not "terminated". Activities are destroyed. Processes are terminated.

If the activity being started via `startActivityForResult()` is in a separate app from yours, it is entirely possible that your process will be terminated while your app is in the background. You see this a lot with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, for example.

Also, a configuration change can destroy your activity as part of it coming back to the foreground. Suppose you start in portrait mode. You start up the other activity. The user rotates the device to landscape, then presses BACK. Your "parent activity" will be destroyed and recreated.

However, otherwise, the only way the "parent activity" should be destroyed is if you call `finish()` on it.

> I periodically get null pointer exception when onActivityResult() is called for some variables that were originally set in the parent activity, but if the parent activity had been destroyed before return from the child activity, then these variables will no long be valid.

You need to repopulate those variables, such as by saving their values in the `onSaveInstanceState()` `Bundle` and restoring them in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. This will handle both the process-was-terminated scenario (assuming the user returns to you reasonably quickly) and the configuration-change scenario.

Comment: This is happening with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. Your answer is pointing me in the right direction. Since this is not always happening, would it make sense to turn on the "don't keep activities" debug flag, to make sure that my app is properly handling this condition ALL the time?

Comment: @GaryKipnis: You could do that, though I tend to forget that the flag is set. :-)